# I need to make select inside another select (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, subquery

in the select statement below I have 707 row

```
select detail_serial, Price from apa_invoice_detail
```

and I have another select statement which is

```
 Select   max(detail_serial)
         ,asc_item.item_name_2
         ,asc_group.group_name_2
 From apa_invoice_detail 
 inner join asc_item on asc_item.item_id=apa_invoice_detail.item_id
 inner join asc_group on asc_group.group_id=asc_item.group_id
 Group by  asc_item.item_name_2, asc_group.group_name_2
```

and this one gives me 197 row

I need to get the price from the first statement for the detail_serial in the second statement (for only 197 row)

I tried this:

```
select detail_serial, Price from apa_invoice_detail where detail_serial in
    (Select max(detail_serial)
           ,asc_item.item_name_2
           ,asc_group.group_name_2
   From apa_invoice_detail 
   inner join asc_item on asc_item.item_id=apa_invoice_detail.item_id
   inner join asc_group on asc_group.group_id=asc_item.group_id
   Group by  asc_item.item_name_2, asc_group.group_name_2)
```

but it gives me "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

How can I solve this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the columns in the inner select statement

```
select detail_serial, Price from apa_invoice_detail where detail_serial in
(Select max(detail_serial)
     From apa_invoice_detail 
     inner join asc_item on asc_item.item_id=apa_invoice_detail.item_id
     inner join asc_group on asc_group.group_id=asc_item.group_id
     Group by  asc_item.item_name_2, asc_group.group_name_2)
```

Comment: Thank you too much

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.

```
;WITH SecondQueryResults AS
(
    Select   max(detail_serial) detail_serial
                , asc_item.item_name_2
                , asc_group.group_name_2
        From apa_invoice_detail 
             inner join asc_item on asc_item.item_id=apa_invoice_detail.item_id
             inner join asc_group on asc_group.group_id=asc_item.group_id
        Group by  asc_item.item_name_2, asc_group.group_name_2
)
select 
    detail_serial, 
    Price 
from 
    apa_invoice_detail T
where 
    EXISTS (SELECT 'serial exists on query result' FROM SecondQueryResults AS S WHERE S.detail_serial = T.detail_serial)
```

... or just select 1 column (the `detail_serial`) inside your `IN` subquery.